# In transfer learning what is the custom part of the network called?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, transfer-learning

I was wondering if the part of the network with frozen weights has a specific name. Similarly, I'd want to know whether the custom-made part also has a specific name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is any scientific terminology for the part of the model, however, researchers do use the terminology for the tasks and domains for the pre-trained and custom models being used for transfer learning - **Source and Target tasks / domains**.

[image]

More information to this definition can be found in the IEEE paper [A Survey on Transfer Learning (Sinno Jialin Pan and Qiang Yang)](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5288526)

[image]

**Side Note:** In my personal experience though, in industry, we usually call the Source task's model as the *Source model / pre-trained model*, and the Target task's model as the *downstream estimator / downstream model*.